# How to solve lookup transform timed out between various frames?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, kinect, ros, openni

I am using hector_mapping to create map of my room. I used openni node to get the depth/image_raw from kinect sensor, I then changed it to laser scan data using "depthimage_to_laserscan" and used that "scan" topic to create hector_mapping. When I run all of these in a machine it works fine and creates a map but when I run "openni_launch" and "depthimage_to_laserscan" on odroid and "hector_mapping" on my machine, I get an error the following error: "lookupTransform base_link to camera_depth_frame" timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base frame". What does this error mean and how did it not occur when everything was running on same machine.?

My odroid and machine communicates over a wireless network. My machine runs ROS indigo on Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: Where is your roscore running? Are you telling your odriod to connect to the roscore on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

### roscore

Assuming your roscore is running on your machine, you will have to set the ENV ROS_MASTER_URI variable on odroid to export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://yourmachine:11311 before launching anything on odroid. This will tell the rosnodes on odroid to connect to the roscore on your machine.

### Check frame rates and delays

There is [tool](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Debugging%20tools) in the tf package to see the TF tree. This will show you also the delays between the links:

```
$ rosrun tf view_frames
```

This will collect TFs for 5 seconds and generate a file named frames.pdf which will contain all the details.

### Machine time synchronization

If you see there are large delays between the TF links you can try to synchronize your machines. To do that you synchronize the time clock on your machine to the one which is running the roscore:

```
$ sudo ntpdate <your-roscore-machine>
```

Sometimes it takes several synchronization attempts to bring down the time difference between the machines.

Comment: My roscore is running on odroid and I have exported ROS_MASTER_URI to the ip address of odroid. So, my machine knows that the master is running on odroid. I think the problem is just with the time sunchronization between my frames as my base_link frame is on my machine and camera_depth_frame is on odroid.

Comment: Added more info to my answer concerning the time issues